# jump to last non-empty cell in row

Tags: vba, excel

Saved a Macro where I would go to to the last non-empty cell in a row by using CTRL+Right Arrow.
The macro, however, was saved by logging the J23 cell.
I want it to be dynamic so that if last non-empty cell changes, for instance, it is N23, it jumps there.

I would like that my other steps would then always link to cells L30, M30, N30 and O30 but in this case they are using relative coordinates (I tried to edit the macro from J23 to N23, for instance, and the linked cells change)

What are the code lines that I can use to make it dynamic the way I need?

Thank you for your help

```
Sub KPILinks()
'
' KPILinks Macro
'

'
    Range("I22").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Range("J23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[7]C[2]"
    Range("J24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[6]C[3]"
    Range("J25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[5]C[4]"
    Range("J26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[4]C[5]"
    Range("J27").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I managed to find out how to lock the linked cells. changing to ActiveCell.Formula = "=L30"

Comment: What are you doing with these cells, are you only trying to select them?

Comment: @jmdon. No. Not just selecting them. Wanting to link them always to the these cells L30, M30, N30 and O30.

Answer (score 0):

borrowed from https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()
'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
MsgBox LastRow
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP is asking for the last column (I think).

Comment: @jmdon well luckily the adjustment for column is not only easy, but also found in the link